# Retrieve a million data from database(postgresql) in gsp

Tags: postgresql, grails

I need to fetch million data from database to GSP page,I written query like

```
"select * from tablename";
```

now am able to retrieve only thousand rows at a time if I upload more than that showing error like

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I am not using hibernate. How can I fetch large amount of data in grails project?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: use the **pagination** or use a **query result iterator**.

If you're using Grails, I recommand you to use Hibernate which allow you to create SQL queries without writting them by hand, and will handle all problems related to the security. Morehover, be restrictive on your request: the `*` is not always necessary and may save request time / memory.

### **Pagination**

This is the best way to handle a large amount of data: you just have to split the query in sub-queries, returning a known amount of rows. To do so, you have to use the SQL closures `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

For example, your query could be: `select * from tablename LIMIT 100 OFFSET 2000`. You just have to change the `OFFSET` parameter to retrieve all values.

Thanks to that, your backend will not have to handle a huge amount of data at a time. Morehover, you can use Javascript to send requests to your backend while it's rendering previous results, which improves the response time *(asynchronous scroll works like this for example)*.

Grails has a default pagination system that you can use "as is". Please, look at the official documentation [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html). Maybe you will have to tweak it a little bit if you don't use Hibernate.

### Query result iterator

You can handle a huge amount of data by using an iterator on the result, but it depends on the querying framework. Morehover, with that method, you will generate huge HTML pages, where the size may be a problem *(remember: you have an OutOfMemory, so you're talking about a hundreds or thousands Mo; at one time, the user will have to download them synchronously !)*